# Use of keyword 'this' in IF statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

I have a bunch of objects set up like this:

```
   <input type="checkbox" id="check30" class="check"   name="check30" checked>

   <input type="text" name="toAddress30" id="name30" class="contactNameInput addressField">

   <input type="text" id="contactName30" class="contactNameInput mailName" name="contactName30">

   <input type="text" id="time30" class="contactNameInput hidden mailTime" name="time30">

   <input type="text" id="day30" class="contactNameInput hidden mailDay" name="day30">

   <input type="text" id="date30" class="contactNameInput hidden mailDate" name="date30">

   <textarea class="additional contactNameInput" id="additional30" name="additional30" placeholder="Additional requests..."></textarea>

   <div class="preview1"></div>
```

I need a condition so that if the HTML of any of the elements with class 'addressField' is blank, the entire object is hidden. I wanted to write something along the lines of:

```
if($(".addressField").html() == "") {
  $(this).parent().addClass("hide");
}
```

What I thought this would do was apply my class name 'hide' (which is defined as display: none in my CSS) to the parent div of any .addressField  items that are empty. However, clearly my use of the keyword 'this' here is off because it is not working and in my text editor, it is clearly not recognizing this word 'this' as it is not formatted accordingly. When I change 'this' to the actual id name of this element it works fine so it seems my structure in terms of '.parent()' etc. is OK - I'm just not sure how to use 'this' in this structure.

Comment: Can you also show the parent function where this `if` exists?

Comment: Have a read about [`this` what it is and what it does](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this). It's not a jQuery concept, it's a Javascript one. `Inside a function, the value of this depends on how the function is called.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give the `$(this)` a context so you could use a for loop to loop through all the elements with class `addressField` :

```
$(".addressField").each(function(){
    if( $(this).val() === "" ) {
        $(this).parent().addClass("hide");
    } 
})
```

**NOTE:** The `addressField` is and `input` field element so it has no `html()` attribute, you should use `.val()` to get the value of the input.

```js
$(".addressField").each(function() {
  if ($(this).val() === "") {
    $(this).parent().addClass("hide");
  }
})
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="check30" class="check" name="check30" checked>
  <input type="text" name="toAddress30" id="name30" class="contactNameInput addressField">
  <input type="text" id="contactName30" class="contactNameInput mailName" name="contactName30">
  <input type="text" id="time30" class="contactNameInput hidden mailTime" name="time30">
  <input type="text" id="day30" class="contactNameInput hidden mailDay" name="day30">
  <input type="text" id="date30" class="contactNameInput hidden mailDate" name="date30">
  <textarea class="additional contactNameInput" id="additional30" name="additional30" placeholder="Additional requests..."></textarea>
  <div class="preview1"></div>
</div>

<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="check30" class="check" name="check30" checked>
  <input type="text" name="toAddress30" id="name30" class="contactNameInput addressField" value="Address Field with VALUE">
  <input type="text" id="contactName30" class="contactNameInput mailName" name="contactName30">
  <input type="text" id="time30" class="contactNameInput hidden mailTime" name="time30">
  <input type="text" id="day30" class="contactNameInput hidden mailDay" name="day30">
  <input type="text" id="date30" class="contactNameInput hidden mailDate" name="date30">
  <textarea class="additional contactNameInput" id="additional30" name="additional30" placeholder="Additional requests..."></textarea>
  <div class="preview1"></div>
</div>


<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="check30" class="check" name="check30" checked>
  <input type="text" name="toAddress30" id="name30" class="contactNameInput addressField">
  <input type="text" id="contactName30" class="contactNameInput mailName" name="contactName30">
  <input type="text" id="time30" class="contactNameInput hidden mailTime" name="time30">
  <input type="text" id="day30" class="contactNameInput hidden mailDay" name="day30">
  <input type="text" id="date30" class="contactNameInput hidden mailDate" name="date30">
  <textarea class="additional contactNameInput" id="additional30" name="additional30" placeholder="Additional requests..."></textarea>
  <div class="preview1"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot. I knew that there was something wrong with the context within which I was slotting the 'this' keyword, but I wasn't quite sure what the solution was. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The value of `this` is dependent on the context it's in. An `if` block doesn't introduce a new context for `this`. I think you're probably confused by how `this` can be used inside a jQuery callback function. Only functions and classes introduce a new context. jQuery automatically binds the current element in its callback functions as the `this` value.

So, what you *could* do in order to get `this` to refer to each element, is by performing a function to each of the elements selected:

```
$(".addressField").filter(function(){
  return $(this).value() === ""
}).each(function() {
   $(this).parent().addClass("hide");
});
```

But, what you're trying to do can be easier done with the following code:

```
$(".addressField").filter(function(){
  return $(this).value() === ""
}).parent().addClass("hide");
```

You all`.addressField`s, filter out all the ones that aren't empty, take their *parent*s and then perform what you want on all of them at once.

Answer (score 0):

`$(this)` in JQuery refers to the thing that called the function. For example:

- `$("selector").click(function() { alert(this); });`
  this refers to the DOM element the event handler is being triggered on. Basically what `$("selector")` breaks down to